# Activerecord relation with custom keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

_categoriesI'm trying to re-create some legacy database relation using Activerecord. I'm an Activerecord newbie, by the way I solved every problem until now except for some association where the key is not the ID.

I have two tables:

Product

- id
- model
- name
- type

DataCategory

- id
- name
- tree

The association here is driven by "type" and "tree": how can I create this association with ActiveRecord?

I try with:

```
has_many :data_categories, foreign_key: 'type', primary_key: 'tree'
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think you need inverse foreign_key and primary_key like this:

```
has_many :data_categories, foreign_key: 'tree', primary_key: 'type'
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What is stored in 'type' and 'tree'? The foreign key is the database field on DataCategory that holds the unique id of the Product. The primary key is the database field on Product that holds that unique id. By default, they would be product_id and id respectively. In your case, assuming 'tree' holds the product id, it would be

```
has_many :data_categories, foreign_key: 'tree'
```

It's not necessary to specify the primary key because you appear to be using the default of 'id'